# Некорректно отображается скрипт на Iphone

Tags: javascript, css, ios

Всех приветствую!
У меня есть вот такой скрипт

```
           const text = document.querySelector('.text p');
           text.innerHTML = text.innerText.split("").map(
               (char, i) =>
                   `<span style="transform:rotate(${i * 10.3}deg)">${char}</span>`
           ).join("");
           var width = window.innerWidth
           if (width < 481) {
               text.innerHTML = text.innerText.split("").map(
                   (char, i) =>
                       `<span style="transform:rotate(${i * 5.8}deg)">${char}</span>`
               ).join("");
           }
       })
```

На айфоне отображается вот так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А на других устройствах нормально
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Похоже на айфоне срабатывает условие `width < 481`, но смысл это условия от меня ускользает

Comment: А вообще может лучше в сторону svg посмотреть https://css-tricks.com/snippets/svg/curved-text-along-path/